# Reverting back to higher heading

Tags: org-mode, outline-mode, outline

Here is a sample text to illustrate my difficulty:

```
* H1
L1 Some introductory text for H1
** H2
L2 Some text relating to H2
L3 This is part of H2. But I would like it to be part of H1 only, not part of H2
```

How do I get lines such as L3 out of H2 and into H1 without moving them around? Is there some kind of 'End of H2' marker?

Comment: You cannot: Org mode headlines are strictly hierarchical.

Comment: The question isn't clear, to me. Which lines, etc.? Can you show an example of what you want to happen?

Comment: The only exception to the rule is [inline tasks](https://irreal.org/blog/?p=8418) I think there is still no docs on them except in the code as mentioned in the link.

Comment: @Drew Thanks. I have edited the question to make it more legible. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need H2 to have heading like features (eg you can tag, put properties, etc), you can use inline tasks for this as @NickD suggested (see `M-x find-library org-inlinetask`). You insert one with `C-c C-x t`. These are like regular headings but not part of the hierarchy.

```
* H1
L1 Some introductory text for H1
*************** H2
L2 Some text relating to H2
*************** END

L3 This is part of H2. But I would like it to be part of H1 only, not part of H2
```

If you just want something like folding, you can use drawers I think.

```
* H1
L1 Some introductory text for H1

:H2:
L2 Some text relating to H2
:END:

L3 This is part of H2. But I would like it to be part of H1 only, not part of H2
```